# Calculating Sum of Dynamically Added Inputs

Tags: javascript

I have a form that allows a user to add rows of inputs. I want to be able to show a realtime calculation of the 'total' of some of those inputs. Here is the code I have so far (which only shows the 'sum' of the first price[] input.

```
var insertRow = function() {

    $(".invoice-table").find('tbody')
      .append($('<tr>')
      .append($("<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name[]' placeholder='Item Name'></input></td>"))
      .append($("<td><textarea class='form-control' name='description[]' placeholder='Description' rows='1'></textarea></td>"))
      .append($("<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price[]' placeholder='Unit Price'></input></td>"))
      .append($("<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity[]' placeholder='Qty'></input></td>"))
      .append($("<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='tax[]' placeholder='Tax'></input></td>"))
      .append($("<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='total[]' placeholder='Total Price'></input></td></tr>"))
    );
}
```

Here is the code for calculation the sum onKeyUp

```
function calculate(){
  var elems = document.getElementsByName('price[]');
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
  {
    sum += parseInt(elems[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('subtotal').value = sum;
}
```

Comment: So do you want the total to be updated as they add values in real time?

Comment: yes, when they enter a value into price[], quantity[], tax[], the value should be changed in 'total[]' onKeyUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the onKeyUp event in the 'add a row' script.